# Return multiple values from a highlighted row

Tags: c#, wpf, wpfdatagrid

I need to return multiple cells from a highlighted row in a datagrid and am having some difficulties.

When the selection is changes I am grabbing the selected value:

```
private void dg_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
value = dg.SelectedValue.To_String();
....
}
```

And in the XAML it is bound to the selected value path

```
<DataGrid SelectedValuePath=somevalue ...
```

How would I do this for multiple items in the row.  The somevalue being returned is a unique cell in the row.

Comment: The DataContext property should get you the row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x8x9zk5a.aspx):

```
private void selectedRowsButton_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    Int32 selectedRowCount =
        dataGridView1.Rows.GetRowCount(DataGridViewElementStates.Selected);
    if (selectedRowCount > 0)
    {
        System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < selectedRowCount; i++)
        {
            sb.Append("Row: ");
            sb.Append(dataGridView1.SelectedRows[i].Index.ToString());
            sb.Append(Environment.NewLine);
        }

        sb.Append("Total: " + selectedRowCount.ToString());
        MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString(), "Selected Rows");
    }
}
```

Basically it boils down to getting the selected row rather than the selected value.

I would also suggest using `sender` instead of `dg` since it will be more loosely bound that way. i.e. cast `sender` to the type of `dg` and then use the result of the cast instead of `dg`.